# How to understand the gift of tithes to a priory in 1166

Tags: england, law, monarchy, church, 12th-century

I am trying to piece together the early history of [Eversholt Church](https://village.eversholt.org.uk/eversholt-history/church-history/) in Bedfordshire, UK. The earliest record found so far is in *[The Cartulary of Newnham Priory](https://www.bedfordshirehrs.org.uk/content/publication/cartulary-newnham-priory)* from 1166. Simon [II] de Beauchamp, who oddly has no Wikipedia entry, was lord of Bedford. He seems to have had control of many churches and their income. Simon granted entire churches, and a part of the tithe of other churches, to Newnham Priory.

> Possessiones autem et pertinencie memorate ecclesie sancti Pauli Bed'
> quas eis concessi sunt iste: ecclesia de Rauenysdene, de Ronhal', de
> Bereford', de Wiliton', de Kerdington', de Goldington', de Suguile, de
> Hattele, de Wutton', de Stacheden', de Asple, de Turueye, cum omnibus
> pertinenciis et libertatibus suis; et ecclesia de Grauenhurst' de dono
> Willelmi filii Roberti; et ecclesia de Saleford' de dono Nigelli de
> Salforde.
>
> Concessieciam eis has decimas, scilicet duas partes decimarum in
> molendinis et pannagiis et in ceteris dominiorum de Stotfolde, de
> Hagenes, de Kaishoo, de Lincelade, de Euersholt, de Hunesdone, de
> Puttenho, de Calworth', de Asple, de toto feodo meo in Holewelle.

Google has a good go at that:

> The possessions and appurtenances of the aforesaid church of St. Paul
> of Bedford, which they were granted to them: the church of Rauenysden,
> of Ronhal, of Barford, of Wilton, of Kerdington, of Goldington, of
> Suguile, of Hattele, of Wootton, from Stacheden, from Asple, from
> Turueye, with all its appurtenances and liberties; and the church of
> Gravenhurst concerning the gift of William the son of Robert; and the
> church of Saleford concerning the gift of Nielson of Salford.
>
> To them these tithes were granted, namely, two parts [I think in ten] of the tithes in
> mills and pannages and in the other lordships of Stotfold, of Hages,
> of Kaishoo, of Lincelade, of Euersholt, of Hunesdon, of Puttenho, of
> Calworth, of Asple, of all my fee Holwelle.

- Am I right to understand that Simon granted entire churches to the
  priory?
- Does that mean that the priory would administer the church?
  Receive all the tithes? Appoint the priest? Possibly take rent from
  the priest?
- In that case, how might Simon have come by this control? By what right?

And then Simon grants, I think, two-tenths of the tithes from a number of churches, the tithe being a tenth of the produce from the parish, so Simon is granting 2% of each parish's produce to the priory.

- Might there be some reason why Simon didn't grant these churches to the priory? For example, that he controlled the tithes but not the churches? How might that happen?
- And, do I have that 2% right?

[C H D Grimes](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-14390524) wrote *[A Short History of Eversholt](https://village.eversholt.org.uk/eversholt-history/a-short-history-of-eversholt/)* about 1926 and conjectured that [Hugh de Beauchamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_de_Beauchamp_(sheriff)) or one of his successors commanded the construction of Eversholt Church. Hugh was great-grandfather of Simon and [mentioned in Domesday](https://village.eversholt.org.uk/eversholt-history/domesday-eversholt/) as holding land in Eversholt.

The next mention we have of Eversholt church after Simon's grant is [negotiation](https://village.eversholt.org.uk/eversholt-history/church-history/eversholt-church-the-hospitallers-and-dunstable-priory/) to lease it from the Knights Hospitaller to Dunstable Priory, and it is entirely unclear how that fits in with this. Neither Simon nor Newnham Priory is mentioned.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: [This genealogical entry](https://www.geni.com/people/Simon-de-Beauchamp/6000000002315764663) claims to be the record of Simon de Beauchamp, c. 1150 to c. 1208 and son of Payne de Beauchamp, Lord of Bedford. [Miles de Beauchamp](https://www.geni.com/people/Miles-de-Beauchamp/6000000084223274845) is claimed to have been castellan of Bedford Castle as well as uncle to Simon. [Bedford Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earl_of_Bedford) was apparently lost, briefly, by the de Beauchamp's to [Hugh de Beaumont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_de_Beaumont,_1st_Earl_of_Bedford).

Comment: This was closed as needing more focus - I'm trying to imagine how to refine the question.  Can someone provide alternative phrasing for the question?   @emrys57, I suspect that the phrase "how to understand" is creating some confusion.  What question would you ask of a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?  How would you explain to the rubber duck what you want to know?  (I personally think this is a good question - I'm just trying to figure out how to clarify the focus of the question)

Comment: It is disappointing to see a question with 8 upvotes and NO downvotes closed.

Comment: I posted a new question at https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/66672/what-does-it-mean-to-grant-a-church-to-a-priory which is half of this question.

Comment: @justCal That's indeed a bit puzzling somehow. Technically, I'd see really a case for 'too many (sub)questions in one post' (to which I do not agree entirely. It's difficult & complex, but they are closely connected enough?), so perhaps a bit more focus with cutting out some side issues of less importance might indeed sway Cvoters—but with 8UVs an RO seems also easy? (at)Emrys57: why not try to slim down this upvoted post?

Comment: @justCal Agreed, although I can't agree on the reasoning here: _Ab urbe condita_ or Pliny's big tome would be also "one single primary source", but it would be asking indeed too much here to dissect multiple chapters from either with 'too separated' subquestions in one post (imo: not the case here). My only suggestions here is to perhaps remove minor details to compromise with CVs (as apparently done with moving parts to another Q) & perhaps streamline the phrasing for this one (to make it a more pleasant/'better' read, easier to digest, 'shorter', but that's perhaps platitudinal of/from me?)